# Mac OSX Running Application in bash, alias not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, macos, google-chrome

I'm trying to invoke headless Chrome in a rake task. It works in terminal, but doesn't in the rake task.

I've installed Chrome on Mac OS X, and created an alias to the application: `alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"`

The command `chrome --version` produces the output: `Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100`

`which chrome` produces no output, and that seems odd. `chrome --headless --disabled-gpu` opens and closes a chrome session, as expected.

I want to run headless chrome in a Rails environment, and conducting rake tests:

```
namespace :chrome do
  task test_versions: :environment do
    p `chrome --version`
  end
end
```

Then run the rake task: `rake chrome:test_versions` resulting in:
`/User/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rake: No such file or directory - chrome`

EDIT: After a few comments, I'm not addressing the real problem. I want to use rake tasks to invoke chrome headless in Mac.

Comment: using `` isn't running in your shell, it's running in a subshell via `sh`.

Comment: `system %(source ~/.bash_profile \n chrome --version)` works, is there a way to include aliases in bash_profile in the rails shell commands?

Comment: Shell aliases are really intended for interactive use; they're almost certainly the wrong way to do whatever you're actually trying to accomplish. Please read about the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and tell us what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> `which chrome` produces no output, and that seems odd.

`which` is an external command which know notihng about Bash's aliases. You can use Bash's `type` command:

```
# type chrome
```